# Creating a dict of blank lists that are not the same list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, copy

I am trying to create a dict of lists that can be appended to in a for loop. However, if I create a dict using `fromkeys`, the list becomes a copy of a "pointer", not a new list. For example,

`newdict = dict.fromkeys(range(10), [])`

-- or --

`newdict = dict.fromkeys(range(10), list())`

both yield the same data structure, a dict with the SAME list as the value pair. So that when any key is updated e.g. - `newdict[0].append(100)`, the corresponding output of `print newdict` is:

`{0: [100], 1: [100], 2: [100], 3: [100], 4: [100], 5: [100], 6: [100], 7: [100], 8: [100], 9: [100]}`

Any thoughts on how to avoid this without having to iterate through in a for loop? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Minor: you mean `newdict[0].append(100)`, or `newdict[0] += [100]`, not `newdict[0] = 100`.

Comment: I'm not getting this behavior with 3.3.3: `newdict[0]=100` yields `{0: 100, 1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 5: [], 6: [], 7: [], 8: [], 9: []}`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two most common approaches are to use a dict comprehension:

```
>>> d = {k: [] for k in range(10)}
>>> d[3].append(100)
>>> d
{0: [], 1: [], 2: [], 3: [100], 4: [], 5: [], 6: [], 7: [], 8: [], 9: []}
```

Or to use a `defaultdict` and forego setting any keys at all:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {})
>>> d[9].append(100)
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {9: [100]})
```

As a third option, by using `setdefault` -- e.g. `d.setdefault(k, [])` instead of `d[k]`, like in the `defaultdict` case, you can avoid needing to preset `[]`:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.setdefault(3, []).append(100)
>>> d
{3: [100]}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a dict comprehension?

```
newdict = {x: [] for x in range(10)}
```

Comment: He doesnt want to use a for loop

Comment: @thefourtheye I'm not really sure I would consider comprehensions to be loops.

Comment: If `without having to iterate through in a for loop` in the question means anything....

Comment: I also don't think dict comprehensions are the same as for loops. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do

```
newdict[0].append(100)
```

right?

Answer (score 0):

`fromkeys` is a static method of the `dict` class. The default behavior is designed to set a set of dictionary keys to a **single** value such as set a multi set counter:

```
>>> d={}.fromkeys('abc',0)
>>> d
{'a': 0, 'c': 0, 'b': 0}
>>> d['a']+=1
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'c': 0, 'b': 0}
```

You *can* patch it to call a function for each element:

```
>>> class FixFromKeys(dict):
...     def fromkeys(cls, seq, func):
...         return {key:func() for key in seq}
... 
>>> d=FixFromKeys().fromkeys([1,2,3],list)
>>> d[1].append(1)
>>> d
{1: [1], 2: [], 3: []}
```